# Trim Character and Trim String - Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create functions for trimming characters and trimming strings. I know I can use built in functions of python but I'm trying to make these so I can understand how it works.

```
#Trim Character
def trim_chr(op1,op2):
    """Returns of a copy of the first parameter, where all leading and \
    trailing instances of the second parameter have been removed. Returns\
    unaltered copy of the first parameter if the second parameter is not\
    of length 1"""
    finalword=""
    if len(op2) != 1:
        return op1

    for i in op1:

        if i != op2:
            finalword+=i
    for i in op1[::-1]:
        if i!=op2:
            break
    return finalword

print("trim_chr")
h=trim_chr("zzapplezz","z")
print(h)
```

apple

```
h1=trim_chr("aa+=Baloon+=aaaaa","a")
print(h1)
```

+=Bloon+=
My desired output for this one is : +=Baloon+=

```
h2=trim_chr("ZZappleZZ","zz")
print(h2)
h3=("HelloWorld","")
print("")
```

ZZappleZZ

My desired output for h1 is +=Balloon+=. I only want to get rid of the leading and trailing characters not the ones in the middle.

I'm also sure that removing a trailing or ending string, not just a single character, would be similar to this function. How would I go about it?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `str.strip`:

```
>>> "aa+=Baloon+=aaaaa".strip("a")
'+=Baloon+='
```

Take a look at string functions here: [string-functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html)

Comment: Yea i'm trying to basically recreate that. I don't want to actually use the built in functions

Comment: "I don't want to actually use the built in functions" -- Why? Because they are too fast? They have too few bugs? They're a lot less work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to exit the first loop when you find the first non-op2 character. As written, you're staying in the loop to copy the rest, but that means you're also staying in the loop that deletes the op2 characters. Easier like this:

```
for i in range(len(op1)):
    if op1[i] != op2:
        finalword = op1[i:]
        break
if (not finalword): return("")  # never found non-op2
while finalword[-1] == op2:
    finalword = finalword[0:-1]
return finalword
```

If you want to use "op2" values bigger than one 1 char, you could do something like:

```
finalword = op1
while finalword.startswith(op2):
    finalword = finalword[len(op2):]
while finalword.endswith(ops):
    finalword = finalword[0:-len(op2)]
return finalword
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I'm trying to apply this concept  to removing a whole string.. such as if i had 123abcabc123 ... how would I remove the leading and trailing 123

Answer (score 0):

How about that

```
def trim_chr(op1,op2):
    #copy op1 so you can work on the copy but still have the original to work with
    finalword = op1[:]
    #loop from the begining and remove the matching characters
    for i in op1:
        if i == op2:
            finalword = finalword[1:]
        else:
            break
    #loop from the end and remove the matching characters
    for i in op1[::-1]:
        if i == op2:
            finalword = finalword[:-1]
        else:
            break
    #return the finalword
    return finalword
```

There are other implementations ofcourse but this one matches yours with for loops, but instead of building a new string as you do I just copy op1 and only remove from it

Comment: I'm trying to apply this concept  to removing a whole string.. such as if i had 123abcabc123 ... how would I remove the leading and trailing 123

Comment: You would have to take not 1 character but the length of op2 when comparing. Think over it - how to implement that in the code above